# passing URL vars to a wordpress page and pretty-fying it with .htaccess

Tags: mod-rewrite, .htaccess, wordpress

I have wordpress installed in a directory called *welcome*, and */welcome/samples* is a "page" (created via Wordpress).  It's has a php template waiting for a $_REQUEST['category']

When a user goes to /welcome/samples/**fun**, I want to have "fun" passed to the samples php template in the form welcome/samples/**?category=fun**

But I want the URL to remain in its original form - it's currently replacing the it with the ugly "?cat...etc"

```
# Outside the wordpress block so it won't be overwritten
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^samples/([^/]+)$ /welcome/samples?cat=$1 [R,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /welcome/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /welcome/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I tried Rewriting with simply `samples?cat=$1` but I was getting a 404.  I tried putting in the `RewriteBase /welcome/` in the first block.  without the [R] flag it doesn't work at all.  I keep trying different permutations... and failing:(

Perhaps I'm missing some basic concepts... thanks if you take the time to even read through this:)

ciao

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work for me:

```
RewriteRule ^welcome/samples/([^/]+)$ /welcome/samples?cat=$1
```

I noticed that you're matching on `^samples…` but actually there's no `RewriteBase` yet, so you need to match more (`^welcome/samples…`)